# Removing cell borders from a section of grouped-style UITableView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController initialized with the grouped style and having multiple sections. For one of these sections, I'd like its constituent cells to be completely transparent and have no border. I plan to assign a custom view for every row in this section, but having that custom view surrounded by the grouped table cell looks bad :(

The following makes the background color of a cell black instead of transparent... And I still don't know how to get rid of the border.

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Any pointers? Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5818622/446489 is simplest solution

Comment: @smilealdway That's not for grouped cells. See Intentss's answer below.

Answer (score 159):

**NOTE:** This doesn't appear to be working in iOS7 and above. For iOS7 try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19220030/160917) answer.

For iOS6 and below, to remove the grouped background from a cell in a grouped table view cell:

**This didn't work**

```
cell.backgroundView = nil; // Did Not Work
```

**This did**

```
cell.backgroundView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
```

**If you have moved to ARC** (I've heard this works, but haven't tested it)

```
cell.backgroundView = [UIView new];
```

Comment: This works for me for iOS 4.3.3 too and i prefer this solution, because you can remove the border for each cell individually instead of removing it for all cells of the table view.

Comment: Also set the cell.selectedBackgroundView using the same otherwise it may highlight.

Comment: [cell setBackgroundColor:t.best5bgColor];

Comment: @RyanRomanchuk I've found a way that works in iOS 7: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19220030/1372503

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy, wish I found this earlier. For iOS 7, I think it doesn't add any style for grouped tables.

Comment: @Intentss Brilliant stuff. This works whereas the solution provided below by Fede Mika ie [tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor clearColor]]; does NOT work on iOS6.1. Actually I am using ARC, and your second solution, slightly modified, worked cell.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero]; Just to let people know that I have built a universal app that works on iOS6.1 - iOS10+. So, a lot of these little solutions are very useful for cross compatibility. I was unable to test on iOS6 & iOS7, using XCode 8, so I just created Ad Hoc '.ipa' files for this.

Answer (score 39):

You have to actually set

```
tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

to remove the border of cells.

Comment: The question is asking about grouped tables. `tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone` doesn't work on grouped tables.

Answer (score 37):

The following hack works in iOS 7 – for now. :)

Subclass `UITableViewCell`, and use this cell for the section that shouldn't have separators. 

Override the `addSubview` method in your cell subclass:

```
-(void)addSubview:(UIView *)view
{
    // The separator has a height of 0.5pt on a retina display and 1pt on non-retina.
    // Prevent subviews with this height from being added. 
    if (CGRectGetHeight(view.frame)*[UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 1)
    {
        return;
    }

    [super addSubview:view];
}
```

Comment: Note also that this doesn't work on iOS6, so for iOS6 cell.backgroundView = [UIView new]; is still required.

Comment: @Pin The separators seem to be separate subviews in iOS 7. This code simply prevents them from being added to the cell. It's not very sophisticated though. :)

Comment: in iPad height is 1 , iPhone height is 0.5

Comment: @RanyA.Ishak It's actually not the device type that makes the difference but the screen resolution. I've modified the code to handle both retina and non-retina displays.

Comment: Works for iOS9 as well. Brilliant hack!

Answer (score 23):

This is what worked for with having a Grouped style table

> [tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

Comment: This solution worked for me! And I think this is a better solution than "cell.backgroundView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];" from performance standpoint. I am using Grouped style table, iOS 5.1. Thanks

Comment: I don't know what kind of performance you are talking about, generally setting anything to [UIColor clearColor] is bad idea when it comes to graphics performance because it's a non-opqaue layer that forces the GPU to do transparency blending.

Comment: if I use the above with a grouped tableview, I get that the overall border of the table is gone, which is what I expected. It seems that separator color == table border.

Comment: The other nice thing about this answer is that you can use it in IB too, so you can see your cell as it is meant to look.

Comment: But this removes the separator from the whole table view, not from a single section.

Answer (score 19):

This code worked for me :)

```
[self.tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the backgroundView of the cell to nil. For a grouped table, the cell image is part of that view.

Comment: Didn't work for iOS 4.3.3, or maybe I don't understand what you are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];`

And, don't use `tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;`

I tested with both, if style is none, making the section borders invisible is not working, but instead just change its color, and section border will appear to be none.

iOS seems to be differentiating making an object none and making an object transparent

Comment: The question was how to remove the border, not the separator.

Comment: @JohanKarlsson Though property is `separatorColor`, it affects the border of Grouped style for `tableView` Try it yourself~

Comment: I have tried it. I know it affects both. But nothing in your answer explains this ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

cell.backgroundView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cell.backgroundView = [UIView new];
```

Works like a charm! Tested! iOS6

Answer (score 1):

As of iOS 8, setting the separator attribute to none works as well.

[image: Get rid of cell border]

Answer (score 0):

Setting a content view also gets rid of the border.  Set your custom view to cell.contentView.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to remove cell borders from a section of grouped-style UITableView:

```
[tableViewOutlet setBackgroundView:nil];
```

in the viewDidLoad method.

Answer (score 0):

```
 UIView *backView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
 backView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
 cell.backgroundView = backView;
 cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
 [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a custom UITableCellView then you can add the following method to your view to remove the background view.

```
- (void)setBackgroundView:(UIView *)backgroundView
{
    // We don't want background views for this cell.
    [super setBackgroundView:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just thought I would convert my comment to @Intentss into an answer, because it maybe useful for those, using his solution.

**Using iOS6.1 with a grouped UITabelView, using ARC:**

> [tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

***Does not work***

> cell.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

***Does work***