# How do I remove the border from a grouped UITableView's cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uitableview

[image]

The little white stripe at the bottom really throws off the design and I can't seem to figure out how to remove it.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202965/removing-cell-borders-from-a-section-of-grouped-style-uitableview) question had a high rated response that said to do this:

```
cell.backgroundView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
```

But that removed the grey from my background as well (set with `setBackgroundColor:`) so it didn't work either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this to your `viewDidLoad:` to remove the table borders:

```
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

I didn't understood your problem quite well,but i recommend you to check the height of your cell background view,just as a test put an image as the cell background view and check if the white line stills there:

```
cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.png"]]autorelease];
```

//-----

The code you provide isn't working because you're creating a new blank UIView and setting it as the cell background!The correct method follows:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ApplicationCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        UIView *myBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];
        myBackgroundView.frame = cell.frame;
        myBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor]; <== DESIRED COLOR

        cell.backgroundView = myBackgroundView;

    }

    return cell;

}
```

Comment: Ok,i glad to help you 'user212541',check my edit to know why the code you provided wasn't working!

Answer (score 1):

Try it

```
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
```

Comment: A little explanation would be useful! :)